# Bottom aligning an image within a flexbox li element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to mock up a twitter feed with Flexbox

I've got so far but now I'm stuck!

I'd like for each li item to stretch vertically with flexbox to match the height of the longest tweet, which I have done.

Now I'm trying to get the images to align to the bottom of each of its parents li element (so you don't see the blue underneath any of the images).

Does anyone have any ideas of where im making a mistake please?

Full code on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvGaXQ

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div style="height:600px; color:#fff; padding:50px; background-color:#000;">
      <div id="example1"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to play with `display: flex;`;
Then make the children which can have a bit different height to `flex: 1`;

For your case,
Make the parent `ul li {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}`; then

```
.tweet,
.timePosted {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Here's a working example.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LazPpE

Also if you want to learn more about `flex`, I highly recommend you to visit [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) and [this game](https://flexboxfroggy.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set you li position to relative and then setting the img to position absolute? I also set a min-height to the li for the images to display properly.

li:

```
ul li {
  list-style:none;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px solid #dedede;
  margin:5px;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 550px;
  max-width:300px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align:top;
  background-color: #417abd;
}
```

img:

```
.media img {
  max-width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```